# Filtering file in Unix

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a big problem with filtering output error file. 
The log file:

```
Important some words flags
Line 1
Line 2
...
Line N
Important some words
Line 1
Line 2
...
Line N
Important some words
Line 1
Line 2
...
Line N
Important some words flags
Line 1
Line 2
...
Line N
```

So, some section has word "flags" another not.

Desired output file is:

```
Important some words flags
Line 1
Line 2
...
Line N
Important some words flags
Line 1
Line 2
...
Line N
```

Only section with line, which one was started via "Important" and ended "flags".

All sections have a random number of lines.

So I can't use something like that:

```
grep -B1 -P '!^Important*flags' logfile
```

Because I don't know how many lines will be after/before that line...

Comment: Do the lines not starting with 'Important' start with a fixed word like 'Line', or are they simply lines that don't start with 'Important'?

Comment: Second option. They dont starty with "Line", but there are a lot of logs line. So I can't find pattern to inlcude/exclude them.

Comment: As an aside, `!` is not a negation operator in `grep` and `t*` matches zero or more occurrences of `t`. A better -- but obviously still not even close to working -- command would be `grep -B1 -v '^Important.*flags' logfile` where `-v` negates matches and the `-P` flag never did anything useful in your example.

Answer (score 4):

There are more succinct ways to handle it, but this is fairly clear:

```
awk '/^Important.*flags$/ { p = 1; print; next }
     /^Important/         { p = 0;        next }
                          { if (p) print }'
```

- If the line is important and flagged, set `p` to `1`, print the line, and skip to the next.
- Else, if the line is important (but not flagged), set `p` to `0` and skip to the next.
- Otherwise, it is an 'unimportant' line; print it if `p` is non-zero (which means that the last important line was flagged).

Any lines before the first `Important` line will find `p` is `0` anyway, so they won't be printed.

Comment: Thank You so much! Works perfectly.

Comment: Clean solution; vertical symmetry  (+1)  suggestion: last line `p { print } `

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -n0E 'say /(Important\N*flags.*?)(?=Important|$)/sg'
```